# JS ECMA5: converting object to child class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, prototype-chain

**Code example:**

**ClassA.js**

```
var classB = require('./ClassB');

function ClassA() {
    this.ID = undefined;
    this.Type = undefined;
    ....
}

ClassA.prototype.init = function init(id){
    this.ID = id;

    this.get();

    if (this.Type === 'C' && Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === ClassA.prototype) {
        return new classB().init(this.ID);
    }
}
```

**ClassB.js**

```
function ClassB() {
    ClassA.call(this);
    this.additionalProp = undefined;
}

ClassB.prototype = Object.create(ClassA.prototype);
ClassB.prototype.constructor = ClassB;
```

I have implemented two classes ClassA and ClassB.
ClassB is a child of CLassA and has some additional properties.

The prototype chain for ClassB is setup like this:

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

The information for the objects is retrieved from an API via an ID.
At the time of the API call I do not know if the object needs to be an instance of ClassA or ClassB. So I always start with an object of ClassA to call the API.
When the API returns a specific Type I want to convert my object from ClassA to more specific ClassB.

I tried to call the constructor of ClassB out of ClassA - this throws an error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined*

I don't think I should reference ClassB in ClassA at all, but it was worth a try...

Thank you for helping out a novice! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: *"The prototype chain for ClassB is setup like this"* Please show that in the code block (with the correct class names), not separately in the text. *"So I always start with an object of ClassA to call the API. When the API returns a specific Type I want to convert my object from ClassA to more specific ClassB.*" Please show that code rather than *describing* it. *"I tried to call the constructor of ClassB out of ClassA - this throws an error...*" Please show that.

Comment: Just curious: Why would you possibly need to use ES5 in 2022? ES2015 was seven years ago, and the last remaining major ES5 environment (IE11) is officially dead. And if you really need ES5, you can always transpile down to it (with Babel, etc.).

Comment: I tried to improve the code snippet.
Thanks for your input :)

I have to use ES5 as I am coding for some older industrial software relying on Java and Rhino JS. I would really prefer using ES6 class syntax...

Comment: What does `get` do? Why is it a method of `ClassA`? Why does `ClassA` have an `init` method instead of doing its initialization in its constructor? (That's what constructors are for.)

Comment: What's the point of these two classes? They don't really do anything except holding some properties. Why not use plain objects? Maybe even the ones you get from the API-call.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
get is a method of ClassA (and overridden in ClassB) - correct.
init sets the ID of the object. Sometimes I need to access methods of the object without knowing the ID, this is why I implemented it that way.
Maybe I should reconsider - thanks for your input!

Comment: @Kaici433 - I asked you what `get` did, not what it was. I can see that it's a method of the classes. What does it *do*?

Comment: @Thomas
Both class feature a lot more functionality, I just wanted to make the problem more visible so I reduced the snippet to it's relevant part.

Analogy:
ClassA is a generic Citizen - ClassB is a Senior.
I want to get a persons data, so I create a Citizen an fetch the info.
When the info shows, that the received citizen is retired, I need to change Citizen to Senior. or throw away Cititzen and create a new Senior object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
get is the API-Call that fetches the info I assign to the objects properties.
Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't wait for the Id to be available before creating the instance (and immediately the right one?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you've mentioned this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

You get that because `ClassA.js` and `ClassB.js` have a circular relationship: each tries to import something the other exports. That can be fine in some cases, but here you have code in `ClassB.js` trying to use `ClassA.prototype` in top-level code, and `ClassA.js` importing `ClassB` from `ClassB.js`. You end up with a placeholder for the `ClassA` import and the `Object.create(ClassA.prototype)` call doesn't work.

It's going to be much easier if you define both of them in the same file, thanks to function declaration hoisting.

I'd also modify `init` so that it **always** returns the instance, since you need to return a new object sometimes but not other times. So have it always return the instance simplifies the calling code.

Here's a minimal-changes example:

```js
function ClassA() {
    this.ID = undefined;
    this.Type = undefined;
    // ....
}
ClassA.prototype.get = function () {
    // *** Just for debugging, ID 2 is `ClassB`, any other is `ClassA`
    this.Type = this.ID === 2 ? "C" : "X";
};

ClassA.prototype.init = function init(id) {
    this.ID = id;

    this.get();

    if (this.Type === "C" && Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === ClassA.prototype) {
        return new ClassB().init(id); // *** Use `ClassB`, not `ClassA`
    }

    return this; // *** So the caller always gets an instance they can use
};

function ClassB() {
    ClassA.call(this);
    this.additionalProp = undefined;
}

ClassB.prototype = Object.create(ClassA.prototype);
ClassB.prototype.constructor = ClassB;

module.exports.ClassA = ClassA;
module.exports.ClassB = ClassB;
```

Then using it (just for example):

```
var both = require("./both");
var ClassA = both.ClassA;
var ClassB = both.ClassB;

var obj1 = new ClassA();
obj1 = obj1.init(1);
console.log(obj1 instanceof ClassA); // true
console.log(obj1 instanceof ClassB); // false

var obj2 = new ClassA();
obj2 = obj2.init(2);
console.log(obj2 instanceof ClassA); // true
console.log(obj2 instanceof ClassB); // true
```

---

That said, I think I'd refactor this. You've said that there's a separate `init` method because sometimes you want to use methods on the objects before you have an `id`. That makes me think `ClassA` (at least) is trying to do too much, both things that it can do when it doesn't know what it is (no `id`) and things it can do when it does. The instance returned by a constructor should be fully baked and ready to go. So probably better to split the parts of `ClassA` that don't need an `id` off into something else. That would also mean that `ClassA` didn't have to refer to `ClassB`, which isn't best practice.

I think I'd probably also split `get` off to be separate from the classes, and have it return the appropriate instance.

For example:

`ClassA.js`:

```
function ClassA(data) {
    this.ID = data.id;
    this.Type = data.type;
    // ....
}

// ...other `ClassA` methods...

module.exports = ClassA;
```

`ClassB.js`:

```
var ClassA = require("./ClassA");

function ClassB(data) {
    ClassA.call(this, data);
    this.additionalProp = data.additionalProp;
}

ClassB.prototype = Object.create(ClassA.prototype);
ClassB.prototype.constructor = ClassB;

// ...other `ClassB` methods...

module.exports = ClassB;
```

`get.js` (or whatever):

```
var ClassA = require("./ClassA");
var ClassB = require("./ClassB");

function get(id) {
    var data = /*...get from API...*/;
    var cls = "additionalData" in data ? ClassB : ClassA;
    return new cls(data);
}
```

That provides a much better separation of concerns.

Comment: @Kaici433 - I suspect what you're getting back isn't a `ClassA` instance, just a plain object with the necessary properties. So what this does is create a `ClassA` instance (if the object doesn't have `additionalProp`) or a `ClassB` instance (if it does) and copy over the properties to that new instance, so you definitely have a `ClassA` or `ClassB` instance.

Comment: When I get you right, this would create a new ClassB instance an map the properties of the original ClassA object to it.
My Problem is, that I cannot create a new instance of ClassB inside ClassA.
When adding line "var classB = require('./ClassB');" I get error "Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined"

Comment: I start with an instance of ClassA and call it's get method.
This writes all the received props to self.
Now I want to check if the received properties need me to have an Object of ClassB instead of ClassA which I already have.

Comment: @Kaici433 - FWIW, I've expanded the bit at the end where I suggest refactoring.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanations and suggestions!
I hope I can try it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

> At the time of the API call I do not know if the object needs to be an instance of ClassA or ClassB. So I always start with an object of one class, then when the API returns a specific type I want to convert my object.

Just don't do that. Construct your object *after* the API returns, and construct it with the correct type in the first place.

> I always start with an object of the class to call the API

This is the point where your design has gone wrong. The class should not be responsible for calling the API, it should be responsible only for representing the data and having methods act on the data. Don't start with an empty object that can somehow hydrate itself, have the constructor completely initialise the object from the data passed as parameters.

Put the API call in a separate function, outside of the class. Create a separate class to represent the API endpoint maybe. If absolutely necessary, make it a static method of your base class, it still can create `new ClassA` or `new ClassB` instances then.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and explaining my mistakes!
I guess that's what happens when experience and design basics are missing :(